# How To Set Datetime Globally With UTC Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime

how to make a datetime display that looks customizable at any time to suit each time of users from all over the world?

```
function DateTimeActive(target) {
    $("#" + target + "").datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a',
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is it JQuery? Or Javascript? You tagged it as asp.net-mvc which doesn't seem to be relevant; and got an answer in C#. You probably want to delete this question and start again. But first you might find reading the site [help] useful when it comes to [ask], and this question [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0):

you need to localize your timezone base on the country which is accessing your page or simply fix the timezone to UTC with option to convert to local time zone.

You can convert you local time to UTC with below code i.e.

```
DateTime dateNow = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("The date and time are {0} UTC.",  TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateNow));
```